# Navigate is not exported from react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I got an error that says
Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router'.

I did not import this anywhere in my react app and even comment out all the code that was being rendered and still getting this error.

can someone please explain to me what Navigate is and where it comes from.

Comment: Please include the error message and stacktrace, and associated code that is flagged. Without seeing any code it is impossible to provide decent help. Neither `react-router` nor `react-router-dom` export a `Navigate`.... so you can probably start by searching where a `Navigate` is imported from `react-router`.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing withRouter from react-router-dom

Bottom of class : export default withRouter(className)